# Как можно такое реализовать виджетом nav ?

Tags: yii2

собственно надо что бы в итоге получался на выходе вот такой `html`

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Для него </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <ul class="col-ld-16 col-md-16 col-sm-24">
                <ul class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-24">
                    <li><a href="#">Действие</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Другое действие</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-24">
                    <li><a href="#">Что-то еще</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Действие</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-24">
                    <li><a href="#">Другое действие</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Что-то еще</a></li>
                </ul>
            </ul>
            <ul class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-24 nomobile">
                <img src="image/menuAction.jpg" class="col-lg-10 col-md-10"/>
                <img src="image/menuAction2.jpg" class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1"/>
            </ul>
        </ul>
</li>
```

можно ли такое реализовать в виджите `nav` или придется самому меню делать?

Comment: А что собственно у вас не получается сделать?

Comment: @Ninazu добавлять ul через определенное количество li и фотографии

Comment: Ну начнём наверное с того, что у вас UL, имеет вложенные UL, вместо LI

Comment: ну да если вам так проше то да